# Problem with zmq.IDENTITY in DELAER-ROUTER combination

Tags: zeromq

The following example works.
**DEALER.py**

```
context = zmq.Context.instance()

worker = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
worker.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b'B')  # If identity is set to 'A' - does not work
worker.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")

worker.send_multipart([b'Message from a worker'])
```

**ROUTER.py**

```
context = zmq.Context.instance()
client = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
client.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")

while True:
    reply_from_worker = client.recv()
    print(reply_from_worker)
```

But, as I indicated in the comment, if the identity is set to 'A', the ROUTER does not receive a message anymore. The problem occurred today, while yesterday it worked fine.

Do you know why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem: your code seems to work for me regardless the value of `zmq.IDENTITY`.

Comment: @larsks it also works for me for all the identities except 'A' (which, again, worked yesterday). So maybe yesterday I have not closed the sockets properly and that is why I cannot use it?